# Simplest way to print (with a real-life printer) in C++?

Tags: c++, printing, cross-platform

Most searching for this turns up information about printing to standard output, and the results relating to actual printers mostly involve the Win32 API.

Is there such a thing as a basic, non-OS specific printer API which allows a simple C++ program to print out a file, such as a .txt, or to print its standard output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such non-OS specific printer API with C++.

I would suggest running a command (e.g. with `system` or `popen` library calls) which do the printing, and make that command user-configurable.

Some C++ (or C) GUI framework (e.g. Qt, Gtk, GtkMM) offer an API to print things.

Comment: Doesn't your third statement contradict your first?

Comment: Not really, because non GUI applications (e.g. web applications) probably don't want to use Gtk or Qt (even if they could).